# Threads containing different ways to calculate $e$

Tags: support

I'm reading about constant $e$ in textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher.

I have searched through MSE to found a question containing different ways to calculate $e$. I use such keywords as "constant $e$" and "$e$ identities"  but to no avail.

Please help me find such thread! Thank you so much.

Comment: It is true that searching here for something with one letter is difficult.

Comment: A nice way is to consider the class of (Beukers) integrals $\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n e^{-x}\,dx$, which in the long run prove that the continued fraction of $e$ is $$ e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,1,1,\ldots] $$ Do you need something better than the *best* rational approximations? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbig-list%5D+e But to be clear these are questions not threads.

Comment: This has a lot of matches...   Any big list with $e^x$ in it, for example.

Comment: well that is why the big list tag exists to put a lot on a topic in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Computing the constant $e$ is closely related to evaluating the exponential function, or its inverse the natural logarithm.  If such approaches are of interest to you, try searching for "compute [exponential-function]" or "calculate [logarithms]", etc.

The brackets here denote *tags* in a search.  Some related tags that might be helpful are [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms), [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods), and [computational-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-methods).